# Restrict Adding User to SPGroup Based on a User Property

Tags: 2010, jquery, groups

I have an SPGroup that has permissions that are common to several users but my requirement is only one user (of a given parameter) should be in this SPGroup.

For example, I have a list of Company Owners that can have Contribute access to Pages within the site collection.  But there can only be one Company Owner per Company.  I do not want to have to create a group per Company that all have the same permission to the Pages but I need a way to check before I add a new user to the SPGroup.

I created a "Users" list that stores the company name associated with the SPUser .  Then add that SPUser to the SPGroup.  But now how to I loop through all the SPUsers within that SPGroup to verify the new SPUser doesn't have the same Company Name as another SPUser already in the SPGroup?

I would like to do this client side.  But I will take a server side solution as long as the error message is an alert that can keep the end-user on the same page and not redirect after the error.  I should also mention this in SharePoint 2010!

Users Schema:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Users" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Users" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<MetaData>
<Fields>
     <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" />
     <Field ID="{F9F61730-827D-4437-91D3-C362A3373726}" Name="User" Type="User" DisplayName="Login" Required="TRUE" List="UserInfo" ShowField="ImnName" Indexed="TRUE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" Description="Select yourself here."/>
     <Field ID="{BDEEA156-2556-49EF-BD42-9E98496CBB67}" Name="CompanyName" Type="Text" DisplayName="Company Name" />
</Fields>
</Metadata>
</List>
```

TIA!!